# DataStax Astra Role unauthorized for operation Rest API Table Select

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-astra

I am using Postman to make an HTTP rest call to DataStax Astra Cassandra DB to select on a table but it's telling me I don't have select table permission even though the user for the token I'm providing does have that permission.

Here are my inputs

**Authorization Type**

```
API Key
```

**Key**

```
X-Cassandra-Token
```

**Value**

```
$ASTRA_DB_APPLICATION_TOKEN
```

^ of course replaced with my actual token AstraCS::...

And here is the json response I get back

```
{
    "description": "Role unauthorized for operation: Not authorized to access keyspace.table for SELECT (from source api: rest)",
    "code": 401
}
```

I double checked that the role associated with the token does have the select table permission.

Comment: it would be hard to triage this without additional details like what type of role name did you create for this? See [this API user role documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/manage/org/user-permissions.html#_api_user_roles) for what role should you assign to interact with the database using APIs. Are you trying to access any system tables by chance? Also, refer [here](https://www.postman.com/datastax/workspace/polandll-stargate-workspace/api/64ddc2ad-ded7-45b4-9208-09748d5d4aa9/definition/8eea1b6b-985e-4d1d-8d63-b8a036b66938?view=documentation) & [here